# SQL: How to select multiple xml nodes of the same name into a comma separated list

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Suppose you had an XML field in a database table that looked like this:

```html
<PEOPLE>
  <PERSON>
    <FIRST_NAME>John</FIRST_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>Doe</LAST_NAME>
  </PERSON>
  <PERSON>
    <FIRST_NAME>Jane</FIRST_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>Doe</LAST_NAME>
  </PERSON>
</PEOPLE>
```

And you wanted to get the names of all the people into a comma-separated list (e.g. "John Doe, Jane Doe"). Right now, my SQL query looks like this:

```html
SELECT STUFF((
  SELECT ', ' + FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME
  FROM(
    SELECT
      p.value('(./FIRST_NAME)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as FIRST_NAME,
      p.value('(./LAST_NAME)[1]', nvarchar(max)') as LAST_NAME
    FROM [TABLE]
    CROSS APPLY [FIELD].nodes('PEOPLE/PERSON') t(p)
  ) PEOPLE_ROWS
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST
```

Right now, this works just fine, and I get a nice comma separated list, but I thought there was an easier way to do this. Is there some xpath magic that yields simlar results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is relatively easy to implement by using XQuery and FLWOR expresssion.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata)
VALUES
(N'<PEOPLE>
  <PERSON>
    <FIRST_NAME>John</FIRST_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>Doe</LAST_NAME>
  </PERSON>
  <PERSON>
    <FIRST_NAME>Jane</FIRST_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>Smith</LAST_NAME>
  </PERSON>
</PEOPLE>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT ID
    , xmldata.query('for $i in /PEOPLE/PERSON
        let $person := concat(data($i/FIRST_NAME[1])," ",data($i/LAST_NAME[1]))
        return if ($i is (/PEOPLE/PERSON[last()])[1]) then $person
                else concat($person, sql:variable("@separator"))')
         .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Comma_separated_list]
FROM @tbl;
```

> Output

```
+----+--------------------------+
| ID | Comma_separated_list     |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | John Doe, Jane Smith     |
+----+--------------------------+
```